# Given $BA+B^2=I-BA^{2}$ what can be said about the matrices A, B?

Tags: matrices

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $BA+B^2=I-BA^{2}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Which of the following is true:

1. $A$ is nonsingular
2. $B$ is nonsingular
3. $A+B$ is nonsingular
4. $AB$ is nonsingular

How do we proceed in this type of problems?

Answer (score 10):

$I=BA+B^2+BA^{2}=B(A+B+A^2) \Rightarrow |I|=|B||A+B+A^2|=1$

Hence B is nonsingular

Counter-examples:

For statements 1 and 4 : $A=O,B=I$

For statement 3 : $A=-I,B=I$

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging the identity you can write $BA+B^2+BA^2=I$ and factoring $B$ you get $B(A+B+A^2)=I$ and this proves that $B$ is non singular with inverse $A+B+A^2$

$A=0$ and $B=I$ is a counterexample for 1 and 4 and $A=-I$ and $B=I$ is a counter example for 3

Comment: I agree. Will edit